# Strange behavior of Limit in Mathematica 9 and 10 (bug?)

Tags: bugs, complex

fixed in **10.1**

---

Consider a complex logarithm where the branch cut is defined along the negative axis. Then for $r$ and $\eta$ real and positive we can write

$ \lim_{\eta \to 0} \log(-r+ i \eta) = log (r) + i \pi \\
 \lim_{\eta \to 0} \log(-r- i \eta) = log (r) - i \pi $

which reflects the fact that in the first case ($+ i \eta$) we are approaching the branch cut from above, while in the second case ($-i \eta$) from below.

In Mathematica one can use `Limit` to reproduce this behavior, i.e. by writing

```
Log[-m^2 - I eta]
Limit[%, eta -> 0, Assumptions -> m^2 > 0]
Log[-m^2 + I eta]
Limit[%, eta -> 0, Assumptions -> m^2 > 0]
```

In the first case I get `Log[m^2] - I Pi` and in the second `Log[m^2] + I Pi`. This is correct and fine.

However, if I write

```
a + Log[-m^2 - I eta]
Limit[%, eta -> 0, Assumptions -> m^2 > 0]
a + Log[-m^2 + I eta]
Limit[%, eta -> 0, Assumptions -> m^2 > 0]
```

something very weird happens. In both cases Mathematica 10 returns 
`a + Log[m^2] + I Pi`. To me this is obviously wrong. Since `a` does not depend on `eta` it should not influence the imaginary part in any way. By the way you can basically replace `a` by anything (e.g `1`  or `"a"`) and still get the same wrong result.

I checked this with different Mathematica versions and the problem is present starting with version 9. Mathematica 7 and 8 on the contrary return correct results in all cases.

So is there something I'm missing about the way how `Limit` works, or is it a bug?

P.S. I though that it might make sense to discuss this here before reporting it to WRI. If it isn't a bug, then of course there is also nothing to report.

Comment: Actually I'm surprised that it works at all, since strictly speaking the limit doesn't exist (you usually use a notation like $\lim_{\eta\to 0^+}$ to indicate the extra condition that you are calculating a one-sided limit). However I don't know under which conditions Mathematica considers a limit to be one-sided.

Comment: @celtschk You actually can specify the direction of a one-sided limit using `Direction`. However,  again
`Limit[Log[-m^2 + I eta], eta -> 0, Assumptions -> m^2 > 0, Direction -> -1]` and `Limit[Log[-m^2 + I eta], eta -> 0, Assumptions -> m^2 > 0, Direction -> 1]` give correct results, while `Limit[a+Log[-m^2 + I eta], eta -> 0, Assumptions -> m^2 > 0, Direction -> -1]` and `Limit[a+Log[-m^2 + I eta], eta -> 0, Assumptions -> m^2 > 0, Direction -> 1]` produce wrong output in MMA 9 and 10 but evaluate properly in MMA 7 and 8.

Comment: Definitely a bug.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks, then I'll report it to WRI.

Comment: @celtschk According to the documentation, `Limit` always chooses a direction. By default in case of finite points, it's `Direction -> -1`, but it also "[...] determines the direction from assumptions that have been given [...]".

Comment: I reported it. If you like you can have your name attached to the report. Just let Tech Services know the link to this MSE discussion, and that it was a bug I had filed today.

Comment: Then it is fine, I don't care that much about my name being attached to the bug report. Looks like now I will have to be even more careful when choosing the branch with MMA. Oh well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not an answer, but possible hint as to what's going on:

Try the following in *Mathematica* 9 and 10.0.

```
(*1*) Limit[1 + Log[-a - I y], y → 0, Direction → -1, Assumptions → {a > 0}]
(* 1 + I*π + Log[a]*)

(*2*) Limit[1 + Log[-x - I y], y → 0, Direction → -1, Assumptions → {x > 0}]
(* 1 - I*π + Log[x]  <-- in v9 only.*)
```

In v9, the one with `x` is right, the one with `a` (and any other letter) is wrong.  Clearly, Wolfram is encouraging users to use `x` as the variable.

In v10.0, Wolfram concedes, and all letters give the wrong result.

Comment: Interesting. I tried to look at `ClearAttributes[Limit, Protected]; ClearAttributes[Limit, ReadProtected]; ?? Limit` but it seems like `Limit` is implemeted in C, not in Wolfram Language. Anyway, now it looks more like a bug to me rather than some peculiarity of `Limit`.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in 10.1 on windows:

```
 $Version
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

code for the above

```
 expr1 = Log[-m^2 - I eta];
 Limit[expr1, eta -> 0, Assumptions -> m^2 > 0]
 expr2 = Log[-m^2 + I eta];
 Limit[expr2, eta -> 0, Assumptions -> m^2 > 0]
 a + expr1;
 Limit[%, eta -> 0, Assumptions -> m^2 > 0]
 a + expr2;
 Limit[%, eta -> 0, Assumptions -> m^2 > 0]
```